# Dark Souls 1 DSFix: Why is my screen in the upper left corner?

Tags: steam, mods, dark-souls

I am using DSFix to get 60 fps in Dark Souls: PTDE, but why is my screen in the upper left corner? I disabled DOF and AA in the .ini file like other posts. It still remains there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to turn of Anti-Aliasing and Motion Blur in-game, not in the .ini file.